# How do I revert my .bash_profile back to a TextEdit document?

Tags: bash, macos

I was following a Git course on Udacity and we made some changes to our bash profiles.

Somehow my .bash_profile is now recognized as a Unix executable file rather than a TextEdit document. I can still use it as before, but it bothers me that this change has happened. More than anything I would also like to know what is going on under the hood.

Where on my computer (I'm running MacOS) is the data stored that this is an executable? It doesn't have a file extension so how does the computer know? I changed its 'open with' field found in the 'get info' window but it still identifies as an executable.

Comment: `chmod 0644 ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in unix each file has permission bits which you can see with ls -l. In this case the 'x' bit has been set which means the file is executable. To revert the file back simply execute chmod -x on the file and it will unset the 'x' permission flag making the file a text file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solution!